# Docker not running right after service docker start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up the docker daemon in a saturn cloud hosted image, here is what i did to set it up:

```
url -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sudo sh
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

However, i cant start any images, or do anything with the daemon:

```
jovyan@w-rodri-example-pytorch-32440c07a5bd43b08f4648e6cb393963-7j6j5m:~/modulus$ sudo docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.07-py3

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

A service docker status, tells me it's not running, but i can't get it to start, and there are no error messages.

```
jovyan@w-rodri-example-pytorch-32440c07a5bd43b08f4648e6cb393963-7j6j5m:~/modulus$ sudo service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                                          [ OK ] 
jovyan@w-rodri-example-pytorch-32440c07a5bd43b08f4648e6cb393963-7j6j5m:~/modulus$ service docker status
 * Docker is not running.
```

Is there any fix or any logs to see what is causing the issue?

It's a ubuntu 20.04 image

Comment: What does `sudo systemctl status docker` say about it?

Comment: Hi, thx for answering.
It says:
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down

Comment: SystemD should be installed as the default init system. Are you using WSL or WSL2 or something?

Comment: No , I don't think so, it's a cloud, saturn cloud using a ubuntu 20.04 image. As far as I know, it isn't a wsl.